# Best way to troubleshoot Docker container networking

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker on OSX to use Docker. I find that from time to time the containers I create can't connect to things like `archive.ubuntu.com` or `ping google.com`. I can however `ping 8.8.8.8`

What is the best way to troubleshoot container networking?

Answer (score 0):

Run your container in interactive mode:

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Install ping tool if necessary:

```
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

than you can check ping from inside of docker container:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Whenever I need to troubleshoot networking, I cant get to archive.ubuntu.com which means I cant ```apt-get``` anything

Comment: Try running container based on busybox: `docker run -t -i busybox /bin/bash` it's shipped with most necessary tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how the DNS happens. If you change networks your b2d VM will have the old DNS sever. Restart b2d and you should be fine.

There is also a bug in Go-lang's resolver that won't read new DNS servers unless you restart the app... So docker related commands that need to push or pull will also likely fail.

Comment: Just ran into this again... Restarting b2d doesn't seem to help. Ideas on how to debug DNS? Other than, "this wont resolve"?